# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' when scraping wiki

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Wall/'

cream = requests.get(url).content
soup= BeautifulSoup(cream, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', {'class' : 'infobox vcard'})
type(table)

table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
print(td.text)
```

I am using python3. I was trying to scrap infobox from wikipedia pages, but keep getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'. Anyone knows what's that problem with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of simple mistakes in your script:

1. Remove the last forward-slash ( `/` ) off your url string.

> `url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Wall'`

2. `td` does not exist in your loop, so change it to `tr`:

> ```
> print(tr.text)
> ```